# How do I work with a remote file system from windows using a GUI?

Tags: windows, ssh, gui

I need to log into a Linux server from a Windows PC. So far I used Putty but I don't like typing `ls` and `CD` all the time. Is there a gui alternative to this?

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? Fully administer the Linux server, or just move files around?

Comment: My downvote will become an upvote if you re-phrase the question to something like "What GUIs let me work with a remote file system over ssh?" - To which *the answer* has been supplied by MaQleod

Comment: I need to move files around, view logs, execute scripts. The answers are sufficient. I changed the wording.

Comment: To add my own answer: ExpanDrive (http://www.expandrive.com/) is good.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php), it may meet your needs, depending on what you actually want to do. You can graphically browse the file system and you can open shell windows to run commands as well.

Answer (score 8):

Filezilla is also great with this (sftp). Even better since it is cross-platform.

Comment: Well, actually, this does answer the question rather well. As the author tells he's already using PuTTY, there's really high chances SFTP is supported by the server. Therefore, +1.

Answer (score 6):

Midnight Commander `mc` gives you a TUI. You can run that after logging in with Putty.

[image: Midnight Commander]

<sub>(Note: the above isn't using Putty but shows what mc should look like in Putty)</sub>

Comment: Wow... Looks a lot like Norton Commander.

Answer (score 1):

I use [WebDrive](http://www.webdrive.com/products/webdrive/index.html). It can map SSH and FTP (among other protocols) to a Windows drive letter so you can use normal Windows tools like Windows Explorer to manage your remote files over SSH.

It's not free, but you can use it for 20 days to try it out.

Answer (score 1):

I use [MobaXterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/), It includes different tools like SSH, VNC, FTP and a file explorer.